# Imagemagick convert with font Helvetica

Tags: image, fonts, command, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to create a text with this font : HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman

The font is listed in my Imagick if I do this: `identify -list font`

```
...
 Font: HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman
 family: HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman
 style: Normal
 stretch: Normal
 weight: 400
 glyphs: c:\windows\fonts\helveticaneueltstd-roman_0.otf
 ...
```

My command looks like this:

```
convert -debug annotate -size 720x576 -background none -fill white -stroke white 
-font HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman -pointsize 22 90x25 -draw "text 160,420 'Test 1'" 
-font HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman -pointsize 22 50x25 -draw "text 310,420 'Text 2'" 
-font HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman -pointsize 22 115x25 -draw "text 425,420 'Text 3'" result.png
```

But I get following error (cmd):

```
 convert -debug annotate -size 720x576 -background none -fill white -stroke white -font HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman -pointsize 22 90x25 -draw "text 160,420 'Test 1'" -font HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman -pointsize 22
 50x25 -draw "text 310,420 'Text 2'" -font HelveticaNeueLTStd-Roman
 -pointsize 22 115x25 -draw "text 425,420 'Text 3'" result.png
 convert.exe: unable to open image `90x25': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2702.
 convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
 convert.exe: unable to open image `50x25': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2702.
 convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
 convert.exe: unable to open image `115x25': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2702.
 convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
 convert.exe: no images defined `result.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3252.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
magick convert -size 720x576 xc:none -fill white -stroke white 
-font Arial -pointsize 22 -draw "text 160,420 'Test 1'" 
-font Arial -pointsize 22 -draw "text 310,420 'Text 2'" 
-font Arial -pointsize 22 -draw "text 425,420 'Text 3'" result.png
```

I have changed Helvetica into Arial and used IMv7 syntax. Should be easy to adjust though.

Answer (score 0):

The `-pointsize` setting only takes **ONE** parameter (the point-size), not **TWO** as you have.

Also, the `-font` and `-pointsize` are actually *settings* so there is no need to repeat them - they stay set until changed.